# Accessing nested json app setting in azure app setting returns null

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-function-app

I have an Azure Functions project and locally there is a local.settings.json file with this JSON:

```
"PushFile": {
    "Location": "value",
    "Port": 22
}
```

And I can get the values like so

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("PushFile:Location");
_configuration.GetValue<int>("PushFile:Port");
```

So all good locally. Within the Azure Function App service I have added an app setting like so

```
Name: PushFile
Value: {"Location":"value", "Port": 22}
```

However when I run the function hosted in Azure the values resolve to null.

Is there something I have to enable/turn on within code or azure?

Comment: in Azure, you have to configure your keys as, in this case, `PushFile:Location`, with the value of `value`, and another configuration entry with key `PushFile:Port`with the value of `22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct. In app settings of your azure function, you should define the name as `PushFile:Location` and `PushFile:Port`, like below:

[image]

Then you can use the following code to read them:

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("PushFile:Location");
_configuration.GetValue<int>("PushFile:Port");
```

Comment: The format of parent:childproperty works but I need to access them using environment variables, not _configuration